# List (of) all cubic planar graph with 30 vertices

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Where can I find the list of all possible cubic planar graphs (without triangles) having 30 vertices?

Are there online databases for that?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you will find an already compiled list of such graphs, especially with such a large number of vertices. This [website](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html) says there are 15,415 such graphs on 26 vertices. You're probably looking at somewhere on the order of 500,000 such graphs on 30 vertices. Your best bet is probably to try using [plantri](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) to generate them, although I'm not sure what run-time you would be looking at. I think Sage has an implementation of plantri also, as an optional package [here](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/16970).

Answer (score 1):

There are 181,492,137,812 cubic graphs of girth > 4 (no triangles) on 30 vertices.  At approx.  75 bytes per graph (graph6 format) that comes to about 14TB of data.  I doubt seriously that such a list exists.  There is a list for 24 vertices at https://houseofgraphs.org/meta-directory/cubic .

Comment: You're missing the adjective "planar".